# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.server.QueryServer with Apache Phoenix Queryserver starting

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have a setup with apache `Hadoop 2.10.0`, `hbase 1.5`, and `Phoenix 4.14`.  All working well.  However, when I am trying to connect python with Phoenix I need to enable `queryserver`.  Whenever I am trying to start, I am getting the below error and exit.  Can someone please help on this?

```
2020-06-01 16:59:24.860409 launching /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java -cp /hadoopStack/hbase-1.5.0/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf:/hadoopStack/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.5-bin/bin/../phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.5-client.jar:::/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/etc/hadoop:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/yarn:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/hadoopStack/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/hadoopStack/hbase-1.5.0/lib/*:/hadoopStack/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.5-bin/*:/hadoopStack/hbase-1.5.0/conf
 -Dproc_phoenixserver -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/hadoopStack/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.5-bin/bin/log4j.properties -Dpsql.root.logger=INFO,DRFA -Dpsql.log.dir=/hadoopStack/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.5-bin -Dpsql.log.file=phoenix-hadoop-queryserver.log  org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.server.QueryServer

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.server.QueryServer

close failed in file object destructor:

IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 0):

The Phoenix Query Server is not include by default. It's a seperate jar phoenix-queryserver that you need to include in the classpath:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-queryserver/4.14.3-HBase-1.4

Comment: well this is weird. im trying to use phoenix 4.15 + hbase 1.4.13 and while that version won't have queryserver, there's no matching version for it in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-queryserver/

I guess they failed somewhere there